# How to unit test React components with 'react-testing-library'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-testing-library

I'm using `react-testing-library` for unit testing React components.

```
import React from 'react'
import 'react-testing-library/cleanup-after-each'
import {fireEvent, render, cleanup} from 'react-testing-library'
import MyComponent from '../MyComponent';

const translations = require('../../translations');

afterEach(cleanup);

describe('test MyComponent', () => {
   it('render functional component', () => {
       // extract container which is 'HTMLDivElement'
        const {container} = render(<MyComponent translations={translations} />)
})
```

How do I manipulate the container element as a DOM element? E.g.

```
console.log(container.classList, container.id, container.innerHTML);
```

using the props and methods listed at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element. I can't get any values so far.

Comment: Do you have a *question*? Have you read [the docs](https://testing-library.com/react)?

Comment: its into my comments

Comment: Why? It's prose, why is it buried in a code block?

Comment: Moreover a tutorial by Kent C. Dodds (https://youtu.be/XDkSaCgR8g4) help you lot !